# if user is admin display admin link and logout link else display logout only

Tags: php, conditional-tags

Like the title suggest I would like to create a conditional with the ability to if user is admin display admin link and logout link else display logout only in wordpress. I have created this conditional but for some reason it is not working. I appreciate the help.

```
    <?php 

   $admin_link= ("<?php echo bloginfo("siteurl") ?>/wp-admin/");
   $logout_link= ("<?php wp_loginout(); ?>");


    if (current_user_can("manage_options")) {

    echo ' &middot; <a href="' .$admin_link. '‎">Admin</a> &middot;';
    echo ' &middot; <a href="' .$logout_link. '‎">Admin</a> &middot;';

    }else{

    echo ' &middot; <a href="' .$logout_link. '‎">Admin</a> &middot;';

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: `$admin_link = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ). '/wp-admin/'; 
$logout_link = wp_logout_url();` perhaps this would work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some serious syntax errors - once you open that `<?php` tag, you're running PHP - no need to execute it again (i.e. inside your variable assignment strings):

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // Only show the output below if a user is logged in

    $admin_link  = esc_url( admin_url() ); // Escaped admin link
    $logout_link = esc_url( wp_logout_url() ); // Escaped logout link

    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { // Current user is an admin, show the admin link
        echo ' &middot; <a href="' . $admin_link . '">Admin</a> &middot;';
    }

    echo ' &middot; <a href="' . $logout_link . '">Log out</a> &middot;';
}
```